# Use std::complex in complex LAPACK routines

Tags: c++, casting, stl, lapack, accelerate-framework

I would like to be able to call my Lapack functions from my C++-program with `std::complex<double>`-data types. I realize that the complex data type in clapack is declared (at least on my Mac in the `<Accelerate>`-Framework  as

```
typedef struct { __CLPK_real r, i; } __CLPK_complex;
```

but I cannot come up with a way to use/cast the `std::complex` variables so that they can be processed by lapack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `__CLPK_doublecomplex`corresponds to `std::complex<double>`, so I can cast the STL-type to the `<accelerate>` (i.e. Lapack) data-type.

Comment: FWIW, this compatibility is documented explicitly at the beginning of Apple's `cblas.h` header inside Accelerate.